# Is there any way to make a far jump in i386 protected mode using registers?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, osdev, i386

```
CODE_SEGMENT equ 0x8
jmp CODE_SEGMENT:label1
```

makes a far jump to label1 after loading `CODE_SEGMENT` in the CS register. I want achieve something like

```
mov ax, CODE_SEGMENT
jmp ax:label1
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in [NASM far jump / far call in real mode and ASM code conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15247774/nasm-far-jump-far-call-in-real-mode-and-asm-code-conventions) you could achieve this by using the stack:

```
push eax    ; CODE_SEGMENT
push label1
retf
```

This should also work in protected mode unless it's a task switch (see the [jmp](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/jmp) and [retf](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ret) instruction documentation)

Comment: You mean `push eax`, I think; the whole point was to use a segment selector from a register.  (And yes, in 32-bit mode `retf` does dword pops, discarding the high 16 bits of the upper dword.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ret)