# Questions about indirect jmp in protected mode

Tags: assembly, x86, protected-mode

Because the address xxxx:yyyyyyyy is 32 bits in protected mode, I put a 48-bits address in a piece of memory and want to  give indirect `jmp`, here is what I wrote:

```
mov eax,s1
mov [address],eax
mov ax,SelectorCode32
mov [address+4],ax
jmp  fword [address]

address:dd 0
        dw 0
```

But the nasm shows that `jmp fword [address]` is wrong, I've read some suggestions like  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812797/doing-a-indirect-far-jump-call-in-protected-mode), but didn't help either, so what should I do?

Comment: See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FWord),and in my situation,a method choose a right tss to jmp,so the address is unknown before it runs,so jmp xxxx:yyyyyyyy is useless.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen You are wrong. What you're talking about is the `JMP ptr16:32` form, but there's also `JMP m16:32`. See your Intel or AMD manual.

Comment: Nasm is a nice family assembler and doesn't know the fword. :) Just `jmp far [address]` should do it. Maybe `jmp far dword [address]` if it's not in 32-bit code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NASM's syntax for near and far calls is different from those of TASM and MASM.

Here are the two options for indirect jumps:

```
jmp [fptr] ; jump to CS:0x12345678
jmp far [fptr] ; jump to 0xABCD:0x12345678

fptr dd 0x12345678
     dw 0xABCD
```

You can also always push the far address onto the stack and do `retf`.

Comment: Did this mean that before program is running ,itself already know where to jump?what if i change the address after it is running ?

Comment: I do not understand the question.

Comment: sorry my english is poor,let me ask in this way: if i change the [fptr] after it is running,will the program jump to the new address which i gave him? My purpose is that when the program is running ,i make cpu jmp a tss,than i change another tss2,will it jmp to the tss2?

Comment: If you change the pointer and then use it, you use the changed pointer, obviously. Is that what you're asking about?

Comment: yeah,that's it.i just want to know whether cpu can jmp dynamically,thank you for your help.

Comment: Yep, that's the whole point of having pointers, you can change them to point to different things at different times.