# (Assembly) How do i store a far pointer and use it to jump?

Tags: pointers, assembly, nasm, x86-16, memory-segmentation

I want to far jump:

```
jmp 0x0000:0x7EA5
```

That works fine. However, I want to store the `0x0000` segment and `0x7EA5` offset, then use that stored value instead of hardcoding `0x0000:0x7EA5`.

Is that even possible? I'm pretty new to assembly, so I'm not sure if it's even possible.

Comment: Sure it's possible.  The exact syntax may depend on your assembler, though; which one are you using?  And where do you want to store the pointer?

Comment: If it is NASM (I'll take a guess based on the syntax shown) you can use FAR on a memory address like this: https://pastebin.com/vijUmwDX . I gave an example as some bootloader code as an example although from the address you gave I was curious if you might be doing some kind of kernel and/or bootloader development. It is also possible to push the segment and then the offset on the stack and then do a `retf` instruction.

Comment: @NateEldredge i'm using nasm, i have the wanted segment (0) and offset (7EA5) stored in their own dd variables already (near to the jmp instruction's segment)
`returnOffset dd 0x7EA5
returnSeg dd 0x0000`
i'd like the pointer to also be stored near the jmp instruction so that i can do something like 'jmp pointer', if possible

Comment: The pastebin link in my post offers up a couple ways to do it with NASM. One of the ways seems applicable to what you are doing

Comment: @MichaelPetch Oh wow, thank you! That pastebin helped. I moved my stored values into ax then pushed ax and used retf, it's working with the stored values now

Comment: Note the segment and offset are 16 bits (I'm assuming 8086 or real mode) but `dd` indicates 32 bits, so that may be a mistake.  But anyway, the one note is that the offset and segment have to be contiguous in memory, forming a single 32-bit doubleword.  If you had `returnPtr dw 0x7ea5, 0x0000` you could simply do `jmp far [returnPtr]`.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Sure, but OP's previous comment had the segment and offset *each* as `dd` which is probably wrong.

Comment: Also a duplicate of [Jumping to a far address in real mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31944041), but nobody's upvoted my answer so I can't add it as a duplicate.